# How to find an html element using Beautiful Soup and regex strings

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find the following `<li>` element in an html document using python 3, beautiful soup and regex strings.

```
<li style="text-indent:0pt; margin-top:0pt; margin-bottom:0pt;" value="394">KEANE J.
The plaintiff is a Sri Lankan national of Tamil ethnicity.  While he was a
passenger on a vessel travelling from India to
Australia, that vessel ("the
Indian vessel") was intercepted by an Australian border protection vessel ("the
Commonwealth ship")
in Australia's contiguous
zone<span class="sup"><b><a name="fnB313" href="http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/cases/cth/HCA/2015/1.html#fn313">[313]</a></b></span>. 
</li>
```

I have tried using the following `find_all` function, which returns an empty list.

```
html.find_all('li', string='KEANE J.')
```

I have also tried the `find` function with regex, which returns a none object:

```
html.find('li', string=re.compile(r'^KEANE\sJ\.\s'))
```

How would I find this element in the html document?

Comment: it works for me, on `BeatifulSoup 4.4.1`  which version of beautifulSoup are you using?

Comment: I'm using `BeautifulSoup 4.5.1`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the full element before, but I think it has something to do with the `<span>` element present?

Comment: Can `KEANE J` appear at the start of any other text on the page?.

Comment: "KEANE J." shouldn't appear at the start of any other paragraph except this one. "Keane J" might though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it has something to do with the  element present?

Absolutely, in this case, aside from the text node, the `li` element has other children. This is documented in the [`.string` paragraph](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string):

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be `None`

What you can do is to locate the *text node itself* and then get its parent:

```
li = html.find(string=re.compile(r'^KEANE\sJ\.\s')).parent
print(li)
```